# Vagrant connection timeout after being reset/aborted repeatedly

Tags: vagrant, homestead

After I restarted my computer, running `vagrant up` suddenly stopped working, because of a timeout after the connection seems to be aborted/reset too many times.

Log:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' for provider 'virtualbox' is
==> homestead-7: available! You currently have version '8.2.1'. The latest is version
==> homestead-7: '10.1.1'. Run `vagrant box update` to update.
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead-7: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I tried to enable the GUI in my `Vagrantfile` and then run `vagrant reload`, but the same error is triggered. The additional log can be found here: https://ibb.co/7zPcrrh. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seemed to work by destroying the box and making a new one: running `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` again...